# Ajax Call to PartialViewResult does not Replace Div with PartialView

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, partial-views

I've done this dozens of times before and have been testing all morning, I must be missing something very obvious.

I have a form that submits data and if the data already exists, I just want to overwrite that form using a PartialView.  I can debug the code and watch the POST get called and I even watch the PartialView reciev its model and data but the PartialView doesn't get rendered on the screen and my AJAX doesn't return anything to the console so I'm not sure how to Troubleshoot this.

**My Controller**

```
        [HttpPost]
    [Route("Send")]
    public PartialViewResult Send([FromBody] InstantAlert InstantAlert)
    {
        string view  = "~/views/shared/_InstantAlert_Exists.cshtml";
    }
```

**My View**

```
<!-- Form -->

<div id="DivSubmitForm">
    <partial name="~/views/home/_Partials/_SubmitForm.cshtml", model="Model" />
</div>

<!-- End Form -->
```

**My Script**

```
$(function () {

    $(document).on("click", '#btnSubmit', function () {
        if ($('form').valid()) {
            Submit();
        }
    });

    function Submit() {

        //JSON data
        var InstantAlert = {
            url: $('#url').val(),
            userId: $('#userId').val(),
            institutionId: $('#institutionId').val()
        }

        var jsonToPost = JSON.stringify(InstantAlert);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/home/Send',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: jsonToPost,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("Success");
                //$('#DivSubmitForm').html(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

**PartialView**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <strong>This article has already been submitted</strong>
        <hr class="message-inner-separator">
        <p>
            test
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting result in `return PartialView(view, product);`? If yes `$('#DivSubmitForm').html(result);` should show the html

Comment: If you mean, is Product being created and whether View is populated with the path, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh, so I discovered a form tag on my page which means the controller was inevitably always reloading my initial controller....